# Дата в python. Часовой пояс

Tags: python, python-2.x, время, python-2.7, timezone

Требуется преобразовать дату из строкового вида к внутреннему виду питона. Выглядит она так: `u'01/Dec/2016:01:15:23 +0300'`. Проблема в том, что я работаю в Python2.7. А здесь есть косяки с часовым поясом. Всё остальное я сделал. А вот часовой пояс преобразовать не получается. Вроде бы нашёл либу

Всю дату преобразовать, очевидно, как:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date[0:20], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

Выделяю часовой пояс тоже очевидным образом:

```
timeZone = date[21:]
```

Потом пытаюсь заюзать пакет, `pytz`, который почему-то не может сформировать часовой пояс в моём формате. Помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непосредственно записать часовой пояс у меня не получилось. Но, можно привести дату к единому часовому поясу. У меня есть много таких дат. Следовательно я могу поступить так:

```
timezone = date[22:] # Выделяю часовой пояс
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date[0:20], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S') # Выделяю дату
offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(timezone[1:])) # Сдвиг (часовой пояс)
if timezone[0] == "-":
    date += offset
else:
    date -= offset
itemDataOfLog.date = date
```